# using twiiter tooltip with backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

[full sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/kkXAK/)

I have a very simple backbone js structure.

```
    var Step1View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'.page',
    render:function () {
        var template = _.template($('#step1-template').html());
        this.$el.html(template);

    }
});

var step1View = new Step1View();
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        "":"home"
    }
});

var router = new Router;
router.on('route:home', function () {
    step1View.render();
})
Backbone.history.start();
```

This works well however i am unable to get this simple jquery function called.

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tip').tooltip();
});

### Update

School boy error here.  Jquery onload functions need to be placed in the route. I'm very new to backbone so i'm not sure if this is best practice. But the following works.

```
            render:function () {

            var that = this;
            var savings = new Savings();
            savings.fetch({
                success:function () {
                    var template = _.template($('#step3-template').html(), {savings:savings.models});
                    that.$el.html(template);
// put your jquery good ness here
                    $('.tip').tooltip();
                    $(".step3-form").validate();
                }
            })

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you found your answer!  Just wanted to also share that you could scope down your jQuery a bit by doing this instead.

```
        savings.fetch({
            success:function () {
                var template = _.template($('#step3-template').html(), {savings:savings.models});
                that.$el.html(template);
                that.$el.find('.tip').tooltip();
                that.$el.find(".step3-form").validate();
            }
```

What you have in your example works but it's also scanning the whole document every time for HTML with the class `tip` where you could use the element you just created to scan downward only for the tip you just created inside it.  Slight optimization.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found your answer! Just wanted to also share that you could scope down your jQuery a bit by doing this instead.

```
    savings.fetch({
        success:function () {
            var template = _.template($('#step3-template').html(), {savings:savings.models});
            that.$el.html(template);
            that.$el.find('.tip').tooltip();
            that.$el.find(".step3-form").validate();
        }
```

What you have in your example works but it's also scanning the whole document every time for HTML with the class tip where you could use the element you just created to scan downward only for the tip you just created inside it. Slight optimization.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: what is the difference between the answer you gave and the answer given by Bryan Clark?